# Can't add menu item using wxRuby

Tags: ruby, wxruby

I am just starting to play with wxRuby, using the samples which come with it. However, I can't seem to add a menu item. I have tried a bunch of things, but here is what I want to do:

```
class MinimalFrame < Frame
  def initialize(title)
  ...
  menu_file.append(Something, "&Something\tAlt-W", "Do something")
  menu_file.append(Wx::ID_EXIT, "E&xit\tAlt-X", "Quit this program")
  menu_bar.append(menu_file, "&File")
  ...
  evt_menu Wx::ID_EXIT, :on_quit
  evt_menu Something, :on_quit
```

Looking through the other samples, I don't see anything I am missing, but it refuses to work. It works when I replace `Something` with `Wx::ID_ANY`. I tried it with `class MinimalFrame < Wx::Frame` also. I have googled but I haven't found my answer yet, so I thought I'd come here.

Also, I feel silly for asking, but what does the `<` mean in the class def? I haven't come across it in any of the other stuff I have been working on yet.

Thanks!

Comment: I figured it out, but if someone is able to perfectly answer the first part, I'll give you the correct answer. Since there have only been 4 views so far, I don't know if anyone will even find this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to put this earlier in the script:

`Something = 1`

The ID's need to be numbers, and by setting it as a constant, then I was able to use names instead of numbers.

Answer (score 1):

> Also, I feel silly for asking, but what does the < mean in the class def? I haven't come across it in any of the other stuff I have been working on yet.

This signifies inheritance.  MinimalFrame is a child class of Frame.

Comment: Thank you. I had wondered if that's what it was, but I know 'tis better to ask than to assume.